# jQuery and asynchronous response

Tags: jquery

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

 $("#bb").click(function(){
    $("#temp").hide();
 });

  $("button").click(function(){
    $.get("demo_test.asp",function(data,status){
      $("#aa").html("<div id=temp>"+data+"</div>")     
    });
  });

});
</script>

<button>Clik</button>
<button id=bb>bb</button>
<div id=aa></div>
```

URL:
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_ajax_get

Why I cant control element `id=pom` which is returned by `.get` function using `$("#bb").click`??
Why the page doesn't work??

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure too add JQuery Script to your code:

Verify the Console of your browser and check for any error.
Access-control-origin problem is common when testing this sort of code.

Note that the get is set to "test.html" that is the same file.
Save this script as "test.html" and it will work on your desktop for example.

Here is a code that is working:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

 $("#bb").click(function(){
    $("#temp").hide();
 });

  $("button").click(function(){
    $.get("test.html",function(data,status){
      $("#aa").html("<div id=temp>"+data+"</div>")     
    });
  });

});
</script>

<button>Clik</button>
<button id=bb>bb</button>
<div id=aa></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you don't add the element until the Ajax `$.get` request completes. Meanwhile, the call to `$("temp").hide()` tries to hide the element before it is added.

I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but you could move the `$("temp").hide()` call inside the `$.get` callback so that it also waits for the Ajax to complete:

```
  $("button").click(function(){
    $.get("demo_test.asp",function(data,status){
      $("#aa").html("<div id=temp>"+data+"</div>");
      $("#temp").hide();
    });
  });
```